# Using Mathf.Clamp causes object to start at lowest limit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using mathf.clamp to ensure my object flying upwards stays within +/- 45 degrees. I do this with:

```
x = Input.acceleration.x;
rotationZ -= x * sensitivityZ;
rotationZ = Mathf.Clamp (rotationZ, 45f, 120f);
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rotationZ);
```

My object starts at a 90 degree angle, straight up. When I run this code it first forces my object to the lower limit, 45. I want it to stay in the center. I have accomplished this by creating a variable called addFF and when it first starts the script give it a value of 45. Then I add addFF to the first value and then set it to 0 after like so.

```
public float addFF = 45;  

void launch(){
x = Input.acceleration.x;
rotationZ -= x * sensitivityZ;
rotationZ = Mathf.Clamp (rotationZ, 45f + addFF, 120f);
addFF = 0;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rotationZ); 
}
```

So, this adds the variable to the total making it 90 for when it first runs. Then when it is ran again it is set to 0 so it sets it back to 45. This does what I want it to, keep the object facing 90 degrees, when I start but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: What is value of `rotationZ` before clamping? Also it would be interesting to see values of `x` and `sensitivityZ`.

Comment: The value of rotationZ starts at 90 before clamping. sensitivityZ is 2.5f and x does not have an initial value since it gets it from the accelerometer.

Comment: Actually, I want you to write
`Debug.Log(rotationZ);`
`Debug.Log(x);`
`Debug.Log(sensitivityZ);`
right before clamping and check what values is actually in variables.

Comment: Ah, ok. Im at work right now so I havent forgotten. I'll try when I get home.